# Как исключить stacktrace из отчета xUnit / nosetests

Tags: python, тестирование, jenkins, xunit

Есть тесты на python, unittest. Запускаются с помощью [nosetests](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), `nosetests --with-xunit --nologcapture`, полученный nosetests.xml читает Jenkins с помощью [плагина xUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin).

В отчете по каждому тесту есть три блока:

- Error Message
- Stacktrace
- Standard Output

Из них мне интересны первый и третий. В stacktrace показывается совершенно бесполезный стектрейс тестов + дублируется Error Message, так что он не нужен. Можно ли как-то его отключить?

Пробовал использовать различные [параметры nosetests](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/man.html), пока что безуспешно. Меня устроит решение как через конфигурацию nosetests, так и xUnit Plugin. Конечно, можно вручную отфильтровать полученный xml, но не хотлось бы строить велосипед.

Comment: Похоже, что готовыми инструментами - никак. Когда и если напишу плагин для nosetests - выложу. [How can you suppress traces for failed test cases using Nose?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11425947/2790048)